# Solo mining litecoin on OSX

Tags: litecoin, mac

I would like to do some solo mining of litecoin on OSX.  I realize the probability is low that i will hit it. but i like the idea of the lottery.  I have a miner setup (cgminer) and i have successfully connected to a pool.  I have found lots of guides that explain how to do this on Windows like:
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?PHPSESSID=3rq912e407g04cjq8ehdhnk457&topic=83371.0

But what all these guides tell you to do is edit litecoin.conf and then restart litecoin-qt.  But does this still apply to OSX? I don't see a litecoin.conf anywhere.  I have looked in
Library/Application Support/Litecoin
Is it still litecoin.conf in OSX? or is it a different file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

~/Library/Application Support/Litecoin is exactly where your litecoin.conf has to go. Just go ahead and create it.

Good Luck with the Lottery!

Comment: So, i have added that file, and restarted litecoin-qt.  But when i launch bfgminer with the settings: ```bfgminer --scrypt -o http://127.0.0.1:9332 -u username -p password  -w 64 -I 13``` it just hangs and displays an empty terminal.

Comment: Oh, I'm dumb, i had a # in my password. So it works now. One more small question.  How does litecoin-qt know which public key to credit when winning the lottery (say i have a couple public keys).

Comment: Also, when it starts i see ```[2013-05-06 14:31:39] Probing for an alive pool
 [2013-05-06 14:31:39] Network difficulty changed to 396 (2.839Gh/s)
 [2013-05-06 14:31:39] No suitable long-poll found for http://127.0.0.1:9332```
Does this mean i have not set it up correctly?

Answer (score 3):

No suitable long-poll found means that your bfgminer could not find a server that will inform it of a new block appearing on the network. This is correct, since you are solo mining, and litecoin-qt doesn't supply this.

Don't worry, your setup is correct.

Not having LP only means that your miner will get informed a little bit slower by litecoin-qt about a new block a little later, and potentially doing work on a block that has just been solved for a few seconds at most.

Comment: Thank you!  I just ran bfgminer for a couple hours but it is still displaying 0Kh/s.  When i have used bfgminer in pools in the past it would always display a non-zero rate for kH/s. Is this an indication that something is wrong? or is there no kH/s reporting when solo mining?